# Fail to tune censored package in tidymodels

Tags: survival-analysis, tidymodels, r-parsnip

Tidymodels is an amazing package! Censored data is very common in medical research. When I was trying to tune the 'boost_tree' model using the 'censored' package, the error comes:' Unknown `mode` for parsnip model.' Does it seem that 'censored regression' mode was not supported in parsnip? Very desire for solving!

```
library(censored)
library(survival)

library(tidymodels)

set.seed(123)

lung$surv <- Surv(lung$time, lung$status)
lung_split <- lung %>% 
  initial_split(strata = status )

lung_train <- training(lung_split)
lung_test <- testing(lung_split)


set.seed(123)
lung_folds <- vfold_cv(lung_train, strata = status)


lung_rec <- recipe(surv ~ age + ph.ecog, data = lung_train)


boost_spec <-
  boost_tree(
    mtry = tune(),
    trees = tune()
  ) %>%
  set_engine("mboost") %>%
  set_mode('censored regression') 

lung_grid <- crossing(mtry = c(2,3,4), trees = c(100,200,15))

lung_wf <- workflow(lung_rec, boost_spec)

set.seed(345)
tree_rs <-
  tune_grid(
    lung_wf,
    boost_spec,
    resamples = lung_folds,
    grid = lung_grid
    #metrics = metric_set(accuracy, roc_auc, sensitivity, specificity)
  )

tree_rs
```

Comment: The {censored} package is still in development and not fully integrated into all the main packages of {tidymodels}. There is not a concrete timeline yet. My best suggestion would be to wait for a CRAN release of {censored}.

Comment: Thank you! I'm waiting!

Comment: It's now 2024 and we're still waiting…. Any update on this @EmilHvitfeldt?

Comment: We are almost there, we are planning to get CRAN versions of the needed packages over the next couple of weeks https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2024/01/tidymodels-2023-q4/#coming-attractions

Comment: There are a few little things that we are [testing/fixing](https://github.com/orgs/tidymodels/projects/33/views/2) but `pak::pak(paste0("tidymodels/", c("censored", "parsnip", "tune", "yardstick", "hardhat", "finetune", "workflows")), ask = FALSE)` will get you the new versions and some additional documentation on [`tidymodels.org`](https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/#category=survival%20analysis)